# How to change Custom Date Format for HTML Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using react. I have a date input field which looks like below.
[image]

But the format i want is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Output I required:
[image]

I thought it was a easy one. But it tooks me so much of time. I found one solution. But it was in jquery
[image]

I dont know how to use that in react. Anyone Please help me with some solutions. 
Here's the Code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="date" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The OP does not really want to fiddle with the locale presentation of a [date-input's internal `value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value). The documentation notifies ... _"**Note:** The displayed date format will differ from the actual `value` — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed `value` is always formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`."_

Comment: @Peter Seliger, Ya. But I want to change that. Is it possible?

Comment: In such a case the OP should choose battle tested libraries which support locale settings for the input format. The OP does not want to develop a fully functional date-picker alternative oneself. Any less costly approach/implementation will neither fully cover the user experience of the native input element nor the UX of said alternative library-based date-pickers. **Don't there already exist ready-to-use [date-picker components](https://www.npmjs.com/search?ranking=optimal&q=react%20date%20picker)?** (because of the OP saying ... _"I dont know how to use that in react."_)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. In library, i can get that. But I thought it would be possible without going with libraries. I will try with libraries now. Thanks a lot for responding my question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score -1):

The date input value when tracked is an object with methods to extract what you may want. So if you want 'yyyy-mm-dd' you can convert it toISOString then take the first 10 characters of the string using slice.
Lets assume you use a variable `date` to track the input

```
    const [date, setDate] = useState({})
    let newDate
    if(date !== {}){
        newDate = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    }
```

Something like that, for more info, check [this mdn page on the date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Edit:
To switch to another format, you can play with the string

```js
    newDate = newDate.split('-').reverse().join('-')
```

Alternatively, there's a package [react-datetime-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker) that I once used to switch between formats

```js
    const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());
    return(
         <DateTimePicker
             value={value}
             onChange={onChange}
             format='d-MM-y'
         />
    )
```